# Rails: Compile error with attribute name that starts with integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compilation, integer

I am having compile errors. Could you guys help me get aroudn it. This in my view (the third line with 5prime_primer in particular):

```
 <tr>
      <td><%=relation.AmpInfoName%></td>
      <td><%=relation.5prime_primer%></td>
      <td><%=relation.3prime_primer%></td>
      <td><%=relation.Selective_bases_1%></td>
      <td><%=relation.Selective_bases_2%></td>
 </tr>
```

Produces this error:

```
compile error
/usr/home/benjamin/locus/app/views/locus_table/show.html.erb:314: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot
...tput_buffer.append= (relation.5prime_primer);@output_buffer....
                              ^
/usr/home/benjamin/locus/app/views/locus_table/show.html.erb:314: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER
...put_buffer.append= (relation.5prime_primer);@output_buffer.s...
                              ^
/usr/home/benjamin/locus/app/views/locus_table/show.html.erb:315: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot
...tput_buffer.append= (relation.3prime_primer);@output_buffer....
                              ^
/usr/home/benjamin/locus/app/views/locus_table/show.html.erb:315: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER
...put_buffer.append= (relation.3prime_primer);@output_buffer.s...
                              ^
/usr/home/benjamin/locus/app/views/locus_table/show.html.erb:338: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot
...tput_buffer.append= (relation.5prime_primer);@output_buffer....
                              ^
/usr/home/benjamin/locus/app/views/locus_table/show.html.erb:338: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER
...put_buffer.append= (relation.5prime_primer);@output_buffer.s...
                              ^
/usr/home/benjamin/locus/app/views/locus_table/show.html.erb:339: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot
...tput_buffer.append= (relation.3prime_primer);@output_buffer....
                              ^
/usr/home/benjamin/locus/app/views/locus_table/show.html.erb:339: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER
...put_buffer.append= (relation.3prime_primer);@output_buffer.s...
                              ^
/usr/home/benjamin/locus/app/views/locus_table/show.html.erb:354: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot
...tput_buffer.append= (relation.5prime_primer);@output_buffer....
                              ^
/usr/home/benjamin/locus/app/views/locus_table/show.html.erb:354: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER
...put_buffer.append= (relation.5prime_primer);@output_buffer.s...
                              ^
/usr/home/benjamin/locus/app/views/locus_table/show.html.erb:355: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot
...tput_buffer.append= (relation.3prime_primer);@output_buffer....
                              ^
/usr/home/benjamin/locus/app/views/locus_table/show.html.erb:355: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER
...put_buffer.append= (relation.3prime_primer);@output_buffer.s...
```

Could you guys help me figure out how to get around this?

Comment: As in most languages, ruby identifiers may not start with a numeric character.

Comment: what do you suggest i do? I did not build up this database and I am stuck using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby method names can't start with numbers. You can however define you own accessors:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def three_prime_primer
    read_attribute '3_prime_primer'
  end

  def three_prime_primer=(value)
    write_attribute '3_prime_primer', value
  end
end
```

It wouldn't be hard to wrap this up in a little method so that you could do

```
access_attribute '3_prime_primer', :as => 'three_prime_primer'
```

Comment: Hhah you got there a little faster than me :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I defined a method in my model and then looked up the attribute using a hashmap:

```
class AmplificationInfoTable < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_accessor :all
        def fiveprime_primer
                attributes["5prime_primer"]
        end
end
```

This allowed me to do things such as:

```
relation.fiveprime_primer
```

Peace!